# Adding operations for choices for the Contdown problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I'm trying to make a small program to solve the countdown problem. Basically, given a number `n` and a vector of numbers, the problem outputs if `n` can be constructed applying simple operations (say addition, div, mult, and subs).
It's okay to not to use all the elements of the vector of numbers, but each number has to be used one time maximum.

The input I'm trying to give to the program is a string with reverse polish notation, so I made a small function to solve this kind of expressions.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool is_number(const std::string& s) {
    string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while (it != s.end() && std::isdigit(*it)) ++it;
    return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}

vector<string> parseInput(const string& expression) {
    vector<string> parsedInp;
    string current = "";
    for (auto token : expression) {
        if (isdigit(token)) {
            current += token;
        }
        else if (token == ' ') {
            if (current != "") {
                parsedInp.push_back(current);
                current = "";
            }
        }
        else {
            parsedInp.push_back(string(1, token));
        }
    }
    return parsedInp;
}

double operateExpression(const vector<string>& parsedInp) {
    stack<double> expression;
    for (auto token : parsedInp) {
        if (is_number(token)) {
            expression.push(stod(token));
        }
        else {
            double op1 = expression.top();
            expression.pop();
            double op2 = expression.top();
            expression.pop();
            if (token == "+") {
                expression.push(op1 + op2);
            }           
            if (token == "-") {
                expression.push(op1 - op2);
            }           
            if (token == "*") {
                expression.push(op1 * op2);
            }           
            if (token == "/") {
                expression.push(op1 / op2);
            }
        }
    }
    return expression.top();
}


string getSolution(vector<string> inp, const int target) {
    vector<string> op = { "+", "-", "*", "/", "" };
    //TODO....
    
}


int main() {
    string expression;
    getline(cin, expression);
    vector<string> parsedInp = parseInput(expression);
    cout << operateExpression(parsedInp) << endl;
}
```

So my first instinct was to create all possible permutations of the vector, and then try to concatenate the operations in the vector, but the problem that I'm facing now is that I can not find an easy way to do it. I can't concatenate it carelessly, because `operateExpression` would fail, but I don't want to use `try` and `catch` for this problem. Also, I think there should be an easier way to do it.

Basically, the problem is that I don't know a good way to generate all possible expressions for all the subsets and permutations of the original vector. For instance, if I have `(2,5)` as an input, there are the possible expressions:
`2 5 +`
`2 5 -`
`2 5 /`
`2 5 *`
(And also the same operations with `5` as first argument.

For `(2,5,4`):
(all of the above plus...)
`(2 5 + 4 +)`
`(2 5 - 4 +)`
...
And all of the permutations for the above.

So is there any better way to write `getSolution` here?
Thanks.

Edit:
Input example: `(100,4,17,9,3,2)` and `n = 37` -> `17 100 3 2 + / +` (order doesn't matter)

**READ THIS**

Edit2:
I added a function that generates a matrix with all the possible choices for a vector (with repetitions) as the following:

```
void choices(const vector<int>& values, int& currentValue, vector<int>& currentSet, vector<vector<int>>& combinations) {
    if (currentSet.size() < values.size()) {
        for (auto i : values) {
            if (i != currentValue) {
                currentSet.push_back(i);
                combinations.push_back(currentSet);
                choices(values, i, currentSet, combinations);
                currentSet.pop_back();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically the problem now reduces to being able to add all the possible operations to each one of these entries in the matrix, and here is where I'm lost.
I know bruteforcing is BAD, but I'm only interested in having these 4 operations and 6 values.
Also I'm afraid about the combinatorial explosion...

Comment: Could you provide an input example?

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia done

Comment: You can create all permutations of a container using [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Comment: @Darhuuk but `std::next_permutation` is not going to take care about repetitions, and the operations could be repeated

Comment: @Norhther But that's not what you said in your questions. You said your first instinct was to create all permutations, but that you could not find an easy way to do so. Please expand your question with as much info as possible. Also, having repeated permutations wouldn't make the generated answer wrong, it would just make the program slower. It's not clear whether that's an issue.

Comment: @Darhuuk I can't find an easy way because I don't know how to create all the possible combinations of valid operations for an input. I'm going to edit the op.

Comment: @Darhuuk hope the question makes more sense now

Comment: @Norhther guide me weather I am correct basicaliy we have a vector of numbers and using +,-,/ & * we have to find can using these opereation with above vectors we can generate n.

Comment: @DevParzival yes, but we can use each element of the vector at most 1 time, and we can repeat operations.

Comment: Have some patience we are working on this problem.:)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came up with this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

using uint = unsigned int;

bool is_number(const std::string& s) {
    string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while (it != s.end() && std::isdigit(*it)) ++it;
    return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}

vector<string> parseInput(const string& expression) {
    vector<string> parsedInp;
    string current = "";
    for (auto token : expression) {
        if (isdigit(token)) {
            current += token;
        }
        else if (token == ' ') {
            if (current != "") {
                parsedInp.push_back(current);
                current = "";
            }
        }
        else {
            parsedInp.push_back(string(1, token));
        }
    }
    return parsedInp;
}

bool isCorrectRPN(vector<string>& expression) {
    int ssize = 0;
    for (string token : expression) {
        if (token == "+" or token == "-" or token == "/" or token == "*") {
            ssize -= 1;
        }
        else if (token != " "){
            ssize += 1;
        }
        if (ssize < 0) return false;
    }
    return ssize == 1;
}

double operateExpression(const vector<string>& parsedInp) {
    stack<double> expression;
    for (auto token : parsedInp) {
        if (is_number(token)) {
            expression.push(stod(token));
        }
        else if (token != " ") {
            double op1 = expression.top();
            expression.pop();
            double op2 = expression.top();
            expression.pop();
            if (token == "+") {
                expression.push(op1 + op2);
            }           
            if (token == "-") {
                expression.push(op2 - op1);
            }           
            if (token == "*") {
                expression.push(op1 * op2);
            }           
            if (token == "/") {
                expression.push(op2 / op1);
            }
        }
    }
    return expression.top();
}

void printValues(const vector<string>& val) {
    for (auto a : val) {
        cout << a;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void choices(const vector<string>& values, vector<string>& currentSet, int& nVals, bool& finished, set<int>& valuesInUse, const int N) {
    if (not finished) {
        vector<string> op = { "+", "-", "*", "/", " "};
        if (currentSet.size() and operateExpression(currentSet) == N) {
            printValues(currentSet);
            finished = true;
        }
        else if (nVals < values.size()) {
            for (uint i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
                if (valuesInUse.find(i) == valuesInUse.end()) {
                    valuesInUse.insert(i);
                    for (auto o : op) {
                        currentSet.push_back(values[i]);
                        currentSet.push_back(o);
                        nVals++;
                        if (isCorrectRPN(currentSet)) {
                            choices(values, currentSet, nVals, finished, valuesInUse, N);
                        }
                        nVals--;
                        currentSet.pop_back();
                        currentSet.pop_back();
                    }
                    valuesInUse.erase(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


/*
bool hasSpace(const vector<string>& v) {
    return v[v.size() - 1] == " ";
}

void cleanChoices(vector<vector<string>>& m) {
    m.erase(std::remove_if(m.begin(), m.end(), hasSpace), m.end());
}*/


int main() {
    //string expression;
    //getline(cin, expression)
    const vector<string> values = { "100","4","17","9","3","2" };
    vector<string> currentSet;
    int nVals = 0;
    bool finished = false;
    set<int> valuesInUse;
    choices(values, currentSet, nVals, finished, valuesInUse, 37);
}
```

I'm not going to accept this as an answer because I think this is verbose and there has to be a better way to do it.
I'm only interested in one solution, so the complexity decreases.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int>vec;
vector<char>_oprator;
vector<string>ans;

bool solve(vector<int>);
bool foo(int,int,vector<int>);
void fine(){
    cout<<"fine"<<endl;
}
void display(vector<int>vec){
    cout<<endl<<"displaying"<<endl;
    for(int x: vec)
        cout<<x<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
}
int  n;
int main(){
    _oprator.push_back('+');
    _oprator.push_back('-');
    _oprator.push_back('*');
    _oprator.push_back('/');

    int length;
    cin>>length;
    cin>>n;
    int temp;
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        cin>>temp;
        vec.push_back(temp);
    }
    display(vec);
    int tot=pow(2,length)-1;
    for(int i=1;i<=tot;i++){
        vector<int>arr;
        for(int j=0;j<60;j++){
            if(i&(1<<j) && j<vec.size())
                arr.push_back(vec[j]);
        }
        //cout<<"i "<<i<<endl;
        //display(arr);
        if(solve(arr)){
            cout<<"Gotcha"<<endl;
            reverse(ans.begin(),ans.end());
            for(string s: ans){
                cout<<s<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
            break;
        }
        arr.clear();
    }

    return 0;
}

bool solve(vector<int>exp){
    //cout<<"inside solve"<<endl;
    display(exp);
    if(exp.size()==0)
        return false;
    if(foo(exp[0],1,exp)){
        ans.push_back(to_string(exp[0]));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
bool foo(int stk,int index,vector<int>exp){
    //cout<<"ïnside foo"<<endl;
    //cout<<"index "<<index<<endl;
    //cout<<"stk "<<stk<<endl;
    if(index>=exp.size()){
        return stk==n;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<_oprator.size();i++){
        if(_oprator[i]=='+'){
            if(foo(stk+exp[index],index+1,exp)){
                ans.push_back(to_string(exp[index]));
                ans.push_back("+");
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        if(_oprator[i]=='-'){
            if(foo(stk-exp[index],index+1,exp)){
                ans.push_back(to_string(exp[index]));
                ans.push_back("-");
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        if(_oprator[i]=='*'){
            if(foo(stk*exp[index],index+1,exp)){
                ans.push_back(to_string(exp[index]));
                ans.push_back("*");
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        if(_oprator[i]=='/'){
            if(foo(stk/exp[index],index+1,exp)){
                ans.push_back(to_string(exp[index]));
                ans.push_back("/");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

We are using `recursion` to determine where it is possible to get `n` using the numbers at most once.
Most of the variables are declared outside so if we pass them inside the function it will consume more memory.
`display` and `fine` functions are for debugging purposes. If you wish you could remove them.

`length` is the list of numbers stored in `vec`
`n` is our target which we have to generate.

```
int tot=pow(2,length)-1;
```

tot represents total number of ways we can select a sequence of numbers

```
vector<int>arr;
for(int j=0;j<60;j++){
    if(i&(1<<j) && j<vec.size()) //checking if particular bit is set.
        arr.push_back(vec[j]);   //if its set we are adding it to list.
}
if(solve(arr)){//if solve returns true we got n 
    cout<<"Gotcha"<<endl;
    reverse(ans.begin(),ans.end());  //we have to reverse it to see the orginal ans
    for(string s: ans){
        cout<<s<<" ";
    }
     cout<<endl;
     break;
}
bool solve(vector<int>exp){
    //cout<<"inside solve"<<endl;
    display(exp);
    if(exp.size()==0)
        return false;
    if(foo(exp[0],1,exp)){     //we are always choosing the first number
        ans.push_back(to_string(exp[0]));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
 
bool foo(int stk,int index,vector<int>exp){
```

stk  holds what value we could generate till now.
index is the index of exp vector.
Inside foo we try to make all combination of operators.

If it has any answer it is stored in ans. Just reverse it and it will give the order in which we have to use operators to get n.

Comment: @Norhther did you tried above way of aproacing n ? Does it satisfies your answer?